# Popup script and content script can't communicate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My problem is that I can't seem to get the message `chrome.extension.sendMessage("on");` from my popup.js transfer to my content.js.

Code from the popup.js:

```
function click(e) {
    if ( e.target.id == "green"){
        chrome.extension.sendMessage("start");
        console.info("oN");
        return;
    }

    if ( e.target.id == "red"){
        chrome.extension.sendMessage("stop");
        console.info("oFF");
        return;
    }
}
```

The popup.js receives the message perfectly well when i add a listener to the code. But my content.js can't seem to get it.

Code from the content.js:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.info("ok");
    }
);
```

Manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me. Why do you think that it doesn't work? Can you show your manifest file?

Comment: I updated my question with your request. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.extension.sendMessage` is a non-canonical name.

The old, deprecated API is `chrome.extension.sendRequest`, and the new API is [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), and the event is likewise `chrome.runtime.onMessage`.

---

That said, your problem is trying to send a message to a **content script**. `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` sends messages to extension's own pages; content scripts are not considered such. See the [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage)

> Note that extensions cannot send messages to content scripts using this method. To send messages to content scripts, use tabs.sendMessage.

To send a message to a content script, you have to use the [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage` API call](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) using the tab's `tabId`.

Assuming you want the current visible tab:

```js
function click(event) {
  if (event.target.id == "green") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "start");
    });
    console.info("oN");
    return;
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

If you want *all* tabs, just pass `{}` to `query` and iterate over `tabs`.

Finally, take note of [content scripts inject time quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895377/sending-message-from-a-background-script-to-a-content-script-then-to-a-injected/23895822#23895822).