# Chrome extension: message from popup.js to content.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension, I am trying to send a message from `popup.js` to `content.js`. This needs to happen based on an event in the popup, so it can't be triggered on a message from content or background.

I am using the following code just to test whether the message is being passed.

In `popup.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
             alert(response.farewell);
          });
        });
```

In `content.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");

        if (request.greeting == "hello")
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
;
```

The problem is that the message is only being delivered (alerted) when I open a new tab, not when I am in an active tab.

The idea is that the user is able to choose a setting in the popup which then causes the `content.js` to send through different data. So I should be able to send the message whenever the uses click a specific button.

Could someone please help because in every other question about this I just see the link to the Google page about Message Passing. This code is straight from there.

Comment: Can you try _not_ using `alert()`? It freezes the asynchronous flow, and may cause the popup to close. Use `console.log()` and look into apporiate consoles (the page's console and "Inspect Popup" in the context menu)

Comment: On topic, this could be this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895377/sending-message-from-a-background-script-to-a-content-script-then-to-a-injected/23895822

Comment: Using `console.log` still doesn't work. I have looked at the link you posted, but I am a bit confused by the mention of an injected script, is that what I am doing? Because it seems different. Any other ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: @ALR Where you able to solve your issue?