# Sending from background.js to contentScript.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I did what's in the documentation but I got an error saying  `Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined` in the background page.

my background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
   console.log(response.farewell);
    console.log('ytr');
  });
});
```

The msg is sent because my console.log('test') did print out.

my contentScript.js look like this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

and I did declare permission tabs and activeTab in manifest.json. What else I missed?

Comment: To get farewell's value you can use `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener()` in background page and make sure that your background page is registered in manifest.json [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension)

Comment: @Touhid why use onRequest not tabs.query?

Comment: to get value by sending this funciton  `sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});`

Comment: @Touhid Incorrect. To receive `sendResponse`-sent reply, you need to use the callback of `sendMessage`, not the `onMessage` listener.

Comment: oh. So my conjecture is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If `response` is undefined (and that's what *"Cannot read property ... of undefined"* means), then there was an error sending the message.

In this case Chrome calls the callback with `response == undefined` and sets [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError).

You need to check the error value:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response.farewell);
    console.log('ytr');
  });
});
```

My bet is - your content script somehow did not get injected properly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23895822/934239) for some pointers.

Comment: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Comment: When is that background code triggered? In what event handler?

Comment: I think the background.js run first before the contentScript execute caused the problem?  I use "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }, in manifest.json