# Chrome EXTENSION API sendMessage (after update: 49.0.2623.87)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, updates

Recently, **Google Chrome is updated to new version 49.0.2623.87**.
After this update, my extension stopped working. 
(Previous versions works fine)

Here is the part of my code

```
// Content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, response) {
    console.log(message); // > { action: "start" } - I can see message what i've sent.
    if(message.action == "start"){
        response({result: true});
    }else {
        response({result: false});
    }
});

// Background.js
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
    console.log(tabs[0]); // here is tab { object } what I've expected
    console.log(tabs[0].id);   // here id for example 19

    // Background.js
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "start"}, function(response){
        // RESPONSE = undefined
    });
});
```

Probably something changed in **Chrome Extension Api**?

I tried to research it, but not found for now. I'll keep looking.. but hope that somebody knows about it!

Thanks!

Also, I found this bug in [Chrome bug-tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=586155&q=chrome.tabs.sendMessage&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Comment: Can't tell without knowing how your content script is injected and how you're getting `TAB_ID`

Comment: How are the content scripts injected? Through the manifest? When does this `query` execute? Do you see the content script receiving the message (logging)?

Comment: Manifest:
`"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]`

 `"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },`


Query for Background Script is executed on click on extension icon (in the extensions panel).

Comment: Unlikely that anything changed. Could it be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895377/sending-message-from-a-background-script-to-a-content-script-then-to-a-injected/23895822#23895822)?

Comment: Not really. My problem is that now when I send a request from background to content it comes back empty, hence response=undefined.

The reason I suspect something ha changed is because it's been working like this for several months and we've seen this change today after upgrading Chrome to the latest version

Comment: My point is, maybe you're sending while the content script is not ready (not yet injected).

Comment: Content.js: 
`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, response) {
console.log(message); // > { action: "start" }; I see message that i've sent from background.js.

// but this response I can't see at background
response({result: true})
});`

Comment: Then I can only answer with a shrug and "should work". Maybe an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: I agree. But what drives me nuts is that it used to work before the update. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. The difference is that my listener is on background.js.

Answer (score -1):

As [1] says about `sendResponse`:

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

[1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage

Even though I called `sendResponse` synchronously I still had to return true to get rid of this error.