# Inject content script on extension reload programmatically (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background

I am creating a chrome extension that I want to be able to enable/disable. I have successfully made a popup that does just that. The trouble is, if I reload the extension (or if the user downloads it initially) my content scripts default to being off. I *could* just inject the content script in the manifest.json but that results in the content script being injected for any new tab--which I do not want. The behavior should be that if you download/reload the extension, it is on by default, but then you can enable it/disable it and that applies to every new tab. I have tried to put an initialization in background.js but that does not get called at startup apparently.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Rotten Tomatoes Search",
  "description": "This extension searches rotten tomatoes with highlighted text",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "./icons/icon_on.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "<all_urls>",
      "background"
  ],
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
     "js": ["jquery-1.12.3.min.js"], 
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
   }]
}
```

background.js

```
var isExtensionOn = true;
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('backgournd hit...')"});

turnItOn();

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cmd == "setOnOffState") {
        isExtensionOn = request.data.value;
    }

    if (request.cmd == "getOnOffState") {
        sendResponse(isExtensionOn);
    }
});

function turnItOn() {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "./icons/icon_on.png"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file:"openTooltipMenu.js"});
    //$('#toggle').text('disable');
}
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// show different text depending on on/off state (for icon, handled by having default icon)
 chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "getOnOffState" }, function(currentState){
    if (currentState) $('#toggle').text('disable');
    else $('#toggle').text('enable');
 });
// allow user to toggle state of extension
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle')
toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('toggled...')"});
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "getOnOffState" }, function(currentState){
        var newState = !currentState;
        // toggle to the new state in background
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "setOnOffState", data: { value: newState } }, function(){
            // after toggling, do stuff based on new state
            if (newState) turnOn();
            else turnOff();
        });
    });
})
});

function turnOn() {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "./icons/icon_on.png"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file:"openTooltipMenu.js"});
    $('#toggle').text('disable');
}

function turnOff() {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "./icons/icon_off.png"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "$('body').off();"});
    $('#toggle').text('enable');
}
```

popup.html

```
<some code>
    <script src="./jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./popup.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="popupMenu" style="list-style-type:none">
      <div class="header">Rotten Tomatoes Search</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="menuEntry" id="toggle"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should consider using `chrome.storage` to store persistent data: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @RobM., thanks but does this solve my problem? where can i run my initialization script if not in background.js?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. My architectural approach was wrong. One should inject the content_script globally but check with the script whether or not something should be done. To be clearer, in the script get the status from the background page and do something based on that. Previously, I was only injecting the script once the popup was loaded or once initially when the background was initialized. Additionally, one must loop through all tabs in all windows to update the state in all tabs (if that's what one wants).

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23895822/934239) as well, which explains what happens with your scripts when the extension is (re)loaded while there are tabs open.