# Running Script after Injecting from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject a script into the webpage when a button in the extension option menu is clicked. 
Injection -

```
document.getElementById("button_").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Injecting") ;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
          file: 'script.js'
        });
});
```

However the function that I'm trying to run in script.js , foo() is not running. I'm trying to run it via-

```
window.onload= function(){
  foo() ;
}
```

However this does not work . How do I get foo() to run?

Note- It has to run as an injected script

Comment: 'window.onload' is not invoked because the page is already loaded. Why don't you just invoke your function foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the listener and running "chrome.tabs.executeScript" on click, use the "content_scripts" property in manifest file and inside the script create a listener that will run your function.

Comment: How would I refer to the extension's DOM to set a listener?

Comment: In the same manner as usually. You will have a .js file that will be appended to all the websites you specify in "matches" property of the "content_scripts".

Answer (score 0):

[Sending message from a background script to a content script, then to a injected script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895377/sending-message-from-a-background-script-to-a-content-script-then-to-a-injected) gives an excellent guide on dealing with content scripts and communicating with them.